# Wordpress ACF meta value shows in admin and in frontend but not in db, until I click update in admin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Very strange issue where an advanced custom field `'Available'` is correctly flagged in the admin for the custom post and correctly shows up in the front end, but when queried in MySQL it does not show up unless I click the update button in the admin. Then when I perform a query for that `meta_key` and value it shows up?

I have thousands of records so opening each post individually to update is not feasible. So looking for a method where I can update all posts for the custom post type or any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The query performed that does not show any results (even though flagged in admin and showing in frontend) unless I update the post;

```
SELECT * FROM `wp207_posts` wp
INNER JOIN `wp207_postmeta` wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` AND wp.`post_type` ='artwork' AND wm.`meta_key`='status' AND wm.`meta_value`='0')
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 182
ORDER BY wp.post_date DESC
```

Comment: Show the query that you did

Comment: So the query is looking for custom post type of 'artwork' with a 'status' of 'available' (meta_value=0) for posts older than 6 months.

Comment: The query look ok how did you add the meta key for the acf? I guess you add this ACF field with default value?

Comment: Yes it's an ACF select field with 3 possible values. These were input by the author for each post and they have been doing this for 18 months. The selection is showing up correctly in the admin and on the website, and only shows up in the query once the post update button is clicked.

Comment: Do you know of a function or cron that would loop through all artworks and perform an update? similar to opening each post in WordPress and clicking the update button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is function that will take all the posts with post_type **artwork** with date lower than **182days** and update the post meta "**status**" with the value 0.

Make sure to backup your database before you run it.

```
function updatePosts() {
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM `wp207_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'artwork' AND post_status = 'publish' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 182");

    foreach($results as $p) {
        update_post_meta($p->ID, 'status', '0');
    }
}

updatePosts(); // run the function 1 time..
```